# SharePoint 2013 HomePage customization

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, client-object-model, custom-masterpage

I am looking to hear development options for below requirement. I need to create Homepage for the company as shown in the image. The Body of the page contains various images with there hyper links typically when user clicks on icon it will navigate to respective page. The source of this information will managed in SharePoint list with images and its URL.

Development Options:
I am of the opinion creating visual web part will solve the requirement. I would like to listen if there any other options typically using client side object model.

Environment is SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about using Promoted links? es. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx

Comment: One method I've used in the past which is honestly pretty lazy and can make more work down the road if the content changes a lot but you can just create the Home page as a web part page, and then drop a CEWP on the page and just build that section of the page using straight up HTML, CSS and JS. In your case you would create buttons or just images that link to wherever they need to go. It's quick and it's easy but it can be a hassle to manage if the links change often.

Comment: @Cecilia thanks for the link. Actually I don't need the animation which appears on mouse hover of the tile(looking for plain without animation). In my case I have to show A,B,C,D under heading called category A and under category B I have to display E, F, G, H. In such scenario is it that I have to create separate promoted links lists and added them individually on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a content editor web part attached to a text document hosting HTML to get you where you need to be. You can create a list and use SOAP to connect to the list to automate the display through REST.

If this is something that isn't going to change often I would go the route of using a content editor web part CEWP to host text document with HTML.

There is no reason to customize the Masterpage to complete this.

Comment: There is good probability of new links getting added to the list. However I think if we are using REST services it would take the new items from list and push the changes into the CEWP web part right?

Comment: Yes this will get displayed to the client side application. The page would have to be refreshed to get the latest information but at point in time reference it would display the latest info. You can force refresh page with JavaScript also.

Comment: Thanks. I will develop sample application for test purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Add on column in your list which categorize your links. Prepare a text file which contains HTML "div" tags according to your categories and register your javascript file in this text file. The javascript file contains logic to bind your "div" tags using REST API calls or SPServices or ClientContext and place this file in your Site Assets library. Add a CEWP in your Home page and attach your text file in it.